PHP Var Set Via Javascript Is Not Being Seen as an Int
In the code example below I am getting the width of a device screen via a javascript call.  Using the Responsive Design Mode in FireFox, I set the screen width to 600, and refresh the browser. The values I list in the code below are from running the code with the screen at 600.  PHP sees the 600 value, but doesn't compare it correctly with an actual number.
//php

$currentWidth = "<script>document.write( $(window).innerWidth() )</script>";

print "<h1>Screen Width: $currentWidth</h1>";  // output: Screen Width 600

if( $currentWidth >= 990 ){
  print "<h1>Large Screen: $currentWidth</h1>";
}else{
  print "<h1>Small Screen: $currentWidth</h1>";
}
// output: Large Screen: 600


The if( $currentWidth >= 990 ){ is failing. It should fall through to the else block.

I thought maybe the 600 was not seen as an int, so I printed out the variable type and it shows as String. I tried a couple of casts like (int) $currentWidth and intval, they show/make the value as 0 (zero).
I added a * before and after $currentWidth in the printout to see if anything was there but just not showing.
Not sure what I'm missing. Hoping brighter minds than mine will see what is going on.
Thanks

The PHP is compiled and executed on the server; the JS executes in the browser. There is no JS running when the PHP is attempting to set its variable(s).

See What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming

"// output: Screen Width 600" - Look closer, specifically at the page source in the browser and not the rendered result.  The actual output is: <h1>Screen Width: <script>document.write( $(window).innerWidth() )</script></h1>
